# Creating framed image with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Create the framework of intermittent according to this picture:

[image: picture link(please click here to show picture)]

HTML code:

```
 <div id="frm">
     <img src="img/main.jpg">
      <img src="img/imgT.png">
      <img src= "img/imgR.png">
      <img src="img/imgL.png">
      <img src="img/imgB.png"> 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for edit @FrankerZ

Comment: Try looking into `border-image` and just use ONE image rather than 4 separate ones.

Comment: But my project needs to be part of a 4 so as to move each frame separately  @Paulie_D

Comment: If you really want to use images for specials borders, I suggest you have 8 images, one by corners and one by border orientation. You would then create elements for the borders and repeat your image for each side. The corners images should indeed be placed in the corners of your container element

Comment: This is not what I want .. but your words reasonable and I raised the question because I did not know how to put 4 or 8  pictures in the corners .. If you can work for me ready code until proved your answer@AntoineGuillien

Comment: move such as the attached photo imgR @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="frm" height="100px" width="75px">
  <img class="main" src="" alt="" height="100px" width="75px" >
  <img class="top" src="" alt="" height="1px" width="77px">
  <img class="bottom" src="" alt="" height="1px" width="77px">
  <img class="left" src="" alt="" height="100px" width="1px">
  <img class="right" src="" alt="" height="100px" width="1px">
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #frm {
      position:absolute;
    }

    img {
      position:absolute;
    }

    .top {
      top:0px;
      margin-top:0px;
    }

    .right {
      margin-left:75px;
    }

    .bottom{
      margin-top:100px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. but I need an image instead of border to move one views like Right frame According to the picture attached

Comment: I did not see your update. I have updated my JSFiddle link. Is this more the thing you are going for?

Comment: I will try your code .. Please Wait

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the jsfiddle (In your update) in this post.

Comment: Sorry guys I updated it in the answer, sorry for the confusion. The new link was -> https://jsfiddle.net/1w0bxdy0/5/

Comment: thanks sir @RemanBroder Best answer .. but I dont want main picture fixed i want moved with scroll

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: that great answer but main picture not worked with `width:75%;` @RemanBroder

Comment: If you have changed the picture to use percentage rather than set height and width you will have to change the div and other images to match.